# Given N points with integers coordinates find the number of parallel lines

Tags: algorithm, geometry

1. nC2 will give the number of lines we can form in O(n^2) complexity.
2. Finding the slope of these lines in O(n^2) complexity and store them in an array, say x.
3. Sort x in O(n^2 logn) complexity.
4. Search for the parallel lines in O(n^2) time.

Can we do better?

What if I have to find whether any two lines are parallel and that's it.Can we do that without finding all the lines?

Comment: Post it on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Your notation is somewhat misleading. Actually, 1: O(N²); 2: O(N²); 3: O(N²Log(N)); 4: O(N²).

Comment: If you have to report all parallel pairs (and not just count them), the worst-case is certainly O(N²) - when all the lines are parallel, so that the only challenge is to avoid the Log(N) factor.

Answer (score 1):

As the coordinates are integer, you can use a hash table to store the N² slopes; represent them as irreducible fractions. This should limit the search for equal values to O(N²).

Comment: +1: I'm fairly sure this is in the same complexity class as the 3SUM problem, so this is the best you can do for the most part.